# Create ER diagram from sql file in mysql Workbench

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-workbench, tankauth

I am using **tank_auth** library for authentication in **Codeigniter**. I want to draw ER-diagram for tank_auth sql file.

When I imported sql file (reverse engineering) in mysql workbench it shows all table without  any relationship between tables (users, user_profiles, user_autologin, login_attempts, ci_sessions ).

how could I get Er-diagram from given sql file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench derives relationships in diagrams from existing foreign keys. If your tables use engines that don't support foreign keys no relationships can be derived automatically.

Comment: I've go through sql file and seems that there is no foreign key. I've also used Wordpress sql file but there is also no foreign key available (I'm surprised that Wordpress is not using foreign key for relationship).

Anyway if there is any suggestion so that I can make relationship between tables in my case.

Comment: It's difficult to automatically create relationships. Some tools use name similarities between tables but that's really unreliable. So the only reliable solution is to manually add them once and for all and change table engines to InnoDB. There's no reason anymore to prefer MyISAM over InnoDB (mentioning here only the 2 most common ones).

Answer (score 0):

- Go to to "Database" Menu option
- Select the "Reverse Engineer" option.
- A wizard will be open and it will ask for db configuration/source
- On finish it will generate the ER Diagram for you